# pick properties with values of given type

Tags: typescript

I want to have a type which would allow me to pick only those properties from object which value extends given type, as in example:

```
type PickOfValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = {
    [P in keyof (key-picking magic?)]: T[P];
};
```

so somehow I need to pick keys (properties) of `T` which values are a type of `V` (condition `T[P] extends V` is `true`), I couldn't find any way to approach that so asking here is my last resort of help.

example result:

```
PickOfValue<Response, () => Promise<any>>; // {json: () => Promise<any>, formData: () => Promise<FormData>, ...}
PickOfValue<{a: string | number, b: string, c: number, d: "", e: 0}, string | number>; // {a: string | number, b: string, c: number, d: "", e: 0}
```

Comment: What do you want `PickOfValue<{a: unknown, b: string | number, c: string, d: number, e: "", f: 0}, string | number>` to return?

Comment: `{a: string | number, b: string, c: number, d: "", e: 0}` as all the values are matching

Comment: Sorry, I edited it... check again?

Comment: `b: string | number, c: string, d: number, e: "", f: 0}`, as `unknown extends string | number` is false, yet it matches `any` and `never` types

Comment: Just checking, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably implement it like so:

```
type KeysOfValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = 
  { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];

type PickOfValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = Pick<T, KeysOfValue<T, V>>
```

The `KeysOfValue` type function uses a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type to pull out the relevant keys.

This yields the following result for your example:

```
type Example = PickOfValue<Response, () => Promise<any>>; 
// type Example = {
//  arrayBuffer: () => Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
//  blob: () => Promise<Blob>;
//  formData: () => Promise<FormData>;
//  json: () => Promise<any>;
//  text: () => Promise<string>;
// }
```

Assuming that's what you want to see, then it works.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: wow, I'm so tired that I would never figure that by myself, thanks!